# Express: how the app.set('view engine','ejs') executed innerly?

Tags: node.js, express

So I know the method app.set() is that setting value for a name. therefore, app.get() could get the value by name. but accordingly, if I set 'view engine' to 'ejs',where is the app.get('view engine')? if not have, how dose the app.set('view engine','ejs') work?

thank you for responding this wizard question.

Comment: how about to have config object that is done using nconf, and then accessible anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

It works as You expect:

[image: expressjs view engine]

How it works?

Check this: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L336

From line: 336

```
/**
 * Assign `setting` to `val`, or return `setting`'s value.
 *
 *    app.set('foo', 'bar');
 *    app.get('foo');
 *    // => "bar"
 *
 * Mounted servers inherit their parent server's settings.
 *
 * @param {String} setting
 * @param {*} [val]
 * @return {Server} for chaining
 * @public
 */

app.set = function set(setting, val) {
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    // app.get(setting)
    return this.settings[setting];
  }

  debug('set "%s" to %o', setting, val);

  // set value
  this.settings[setting] = val;

  // trigger matched settings
  switch (setting) {
    case 'etag':
      this.set('etag fn', compileETag(val));
      break;
    case 'query parser':
      this.set('query parser fn', compileQueryParser(val));
      break;
    case 'trust proxy':
      this.set('trust proxy fn', compileTrust(val));

      // trust proxy inherit back-compat
      Object.defineProperty(this.settings, trustProxyDefaultSymbol, {
        configurable: true,
        value: false
      });

      break;
  }

  return this;
};
```